# Cannot install libglade2-ruby dependency for Grism

Tags: 12.10, dependencies, glade

Hey Guys I'm trying to install Grism. I've followed installation steps from http://www.grism.org/install.html, which are fairly simple, just need to install dependencies and than install the deb package. The problem is I cannot install libglade2-ruby dependency !!! Any ideas?
I have ubuntu 12.10 on both PC and laptop - 64 and 32 bits respectively, tried on both. Ideally I want it on my 32bit laptop.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
Package libglade2-ruby is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source 
E: Package 'libglade2-ruby' has no installation candidate
```

- I have tried to install `gnome2-ruby` or `gtk2-ruby` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: when you say "I cannot install libglade2-ruby dependency !!! " what does that mean? is it throwing some error message? are you trying offline/online installation? please provide more information by editing your question.

Comment: `libglade2-ruby` was removed from the package archives. Maybe try `gnome2-ruby` or `gtk2-ruby`.

Comment: neither works, both says E: unable to locate the package .. any other suggestions ? thanks for trying